# Change in Acceleration so a = 0 and v = 0

Tags: calculus

Since velocity is the antiderivative of acceleration $\int{a(t)}dt$. Would we be able to calculate the change in acceleration needed such that acceleration and velocity would equal zero at the same time?

Comment: You can graph this situation easily, by drawing your velocity curve tangent to y=0 with a minimum/maximum at y=0. This would mean that v(t)=0 where y=0, and since it is a min or max a(t)=0.

Answer (score 0):

One needs to start with a function for acceleration that goes to $0$. I assume that at $t=0$ the velocity is $v_0>0$. At the same instant, one starts breaking, so the acceleration is negative. The simplest model is linear dependence of acceleration, but you can use whatever function you want, if you follow the same steps. $$a=-a_0+\alpha t$$
Here $a_0,\alpha>0$. The velocity is given by $$v(t)=v_0+\int_0^ta(\tau)d\tau$$
So when velocity is $0$ we have $$v_0-a_0t+\frac 12 \alpha t^2=0$$
You also have from the acceleration that $$-a_0+\alpha t=0$$

You have now two equations and three variables ($t,a_0,\alpha$), so you would need to add one more constraint. That is up to you. You can say for example that the maximum deceleration is $a_0$, or you can specify that the vehicle should stop in a certain amount of time.